# JPA TypedQuery Type Casting

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to write a group by query for a project. My entity has a LocalDateTime in it and it is written as timestamp in database.

I want to make a selection and group the results by this date only but I couldn't figure it out to cast it from LocalDateTime to LocalDate. My goal is write the below query in Jpa TypedQuery **without using native query**.

```
SELECT company_id, doctype_id, status, created_at::date as p, count("id")
FROM treareport.eareport.report_header
WHERE company_id IN ('company1', 'company2')
  AND created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-23' AND '2022-06-23'
GROUP BY company_id, doctype_id, status, p
```

My query in project:

```
@Query("SELECT new net.sampleproject.AnalyticResponseDTO(e.companyId, e.doctypeId, e.status, e.createdAt, COUNT(e)) " +
        "FROM ReportHeader e " +
        "WHERE e.companyId IN :companyList " +
        "AND e.createdAt BETWEEN :start AND :end " +
        "GROUP BY e.companyId,  e.createdAt, e.doctypeId, e.status")
List<AnalyticResponseDTO> analyticQuery(List<String> companyList, LocalDate start, LocalDate end);
```

Comment: You can use `LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2021,6 , 23), LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)` to effectively search for date. For grouping, you will probably need another field with an `@Converter` which converts from `LocalDateTime` to `LocalDate`

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` in your entity on your LocalDateTime column.
Another way you may use methods of `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter` to convert between LocalDate and LocalDateTime.

Comment: `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` was needed with `java.util.Date`. It is no longer needed with `LocalDateTime`